# Xamarin Forms Disable NamedSize font doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms

I try run this from Xamarin.Forms.Sample repo https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples
Under folder UserInterface/PlatformSpecifics with :
`ios:Application.EnableAccessibilityScalingForNamedFontSizes="false"`

This flag is set to disable scaling of fontsize, however when I go to ios settings Larger Font Size and increase the size, look like that disable doesn't work at all, what do I miss here? or is it a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [PR](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/6345/files#) , it adds the functionality of `disable accessibility sizing for named font sizes` .

You can see in that class it affects the font size returned from **GetNamedSize** method, and check the following screen shot you could find out those controls which will be affected.

[image]

---

So  `PlatformSpecifics` API only works on some specifc controls , it does not affect `ViewCell` and `TableSection` in your scenario .

---

As a workaround , you could replace `TextCell` with `ViewCell` and place a Label inside it ,something like

```
       <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="fdhfihdif">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="{}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </ViewCell>
```

---

Consider raising feature request on github what you want .

Comment: Thanks, might I ask what tool did you use to see this visual tree when search for `GetNamedSize` ?

Comment: `Control + F` , select `Entire Solution`  , Find All .